# Handel Facebook notification click with my iPhone application

Tags: objective-c, iphone, facebook, facebook-graph-api, ios7

Hello Developers,
            I am using Facebook integration for Developing my iPhone application.User can send Request as a Facebook notification to his/her friend for more points.I am confused here. How can I detect Notification is clicked by Receiver? and Which user's Request is Accepted by receiver.Facebook canvas page is Created But there is no application on that page.Is this way to handle everything through my iPhone application With out canvas application..

Thanks,
Have a Nice Day

Comment: _“Facebook canvas page is Created But there is no application on that page”_ – then you will most likely not get your app through Facebook review. If you set up a platform, then you have to have a _usable_ version of your app on that platform.

Comment: you not get this point . suppose like game request . if user send a bomb so at other side user received bomb so how we can detect this object in sending simple Facebook notification . and how we can track other user use this notification to download my app .  My points is if user send facebook request then other user see that and install this app and get +5 point .